# Update showing rows affected but value did not change

Tags: sql-update

I am trying to update a table column processed with a simple update statement and the result is showing that the particular rows are updated but when I run the select statement the values are not changed. Below is the simple update statement I am using. The Processed Column has a datatype Char(2).

```sql
update  airNewFormat
set Processed ='Y'
where TrackingNumber in ('1', '2', '3','4');
go
select * 
from airNewFormat 
with (nolock)    
where TrackingNumber in ('1', '2', '3','4')
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my question. Its the same table AirNewFormat.

Comment: can you show us the structure of table and some data as well? it would be easy to understand the problem.